# Validation Rule if only the value is not NULL

Tags: apex, validation-rule

Hi i am very new to Salesforce. It might be a silly question to ask. I want to fire a vaidation rule for a text field only if it is not NULL. Since i wrote it, it made the field mandatory. I just want it to fire only when it is not null. is there an if option like in JAVA which i can use here. The if option in salesforce is not letting me do it similar to java. The validation rule is wrote is

> AND(NOT(REGEX(Expiration_Date__c ,"^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))/[0-9]{4}$")),
>   RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Test')

The text field is Expiration_Date.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ISNULL(Expiration_Date__c )
```

This will return true if value is null

ohh missed

looks like `Expiration_Date` is text field.

For text field `ISBLANK()`

```
ISBLANK(Expiration_Date__c )
```

Comment: Thank you , it did the trick. i changed my expression to AND(NOT( ISBLANK(Expiration_Date__c) ),NOT(REGEX(Expiration_Date__c ,"^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))/[0-9]{4}$")), RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Test')

Comment: @Dino Most welcome..